Changed filesystem from ntfs to ext4 and lost data
I plugged in my external which hadn't been used in months only to see that Ubuntu was unable to mount the device. I have Kali as a dual-boot as  so it thought I'd try to see if it will be recognised on that OS sure enough I was able to access all files on my external with no hassle at all.
My knowledge on the topic is tiny, but it does interest me so I play around to keep my curiosity sufficiently entertained.
I ended up changing the file system to ext4 from ntfs and have lost all the data on my external, however on Kali it still shows some disk space is being used, although it's not a significant amount at all and on Ubuntu it shows that only 1.9G is being used.....
Most of the files on the external I don't mind doing without, but I did have some docs which are a quite important.
With a bit of digging and researching, I have managed to recover some missing files in the past, but I'm not so positive this time.
What are the chances of me solving this issue? Any advice is greatly appreciated.
update.
PhotoRec seems to be able to find lost data. Has recovered 88Gb so far. Will have to wait to see what it is able to drag up

"changing" the filesystem on a volume involves formatting that disk using the new filesystem, so its no big surprise that your data is gone. if the disk is an mechanical HDD, and the format didn;t overwrite the whole disk, you may be able to find some files (minus their filename and folder heirarchy) from the disk using file-scavaging utilities like Photorec, Recuva, Easus, etc, but if its an SSD, that is quite unlikely. Never restore files to the drive you are recovering them from. good luck.

What are the chances of me solving this issue? Read above. Any advice is greatly appreciated Start by learning the basics; DON'T use Kali.

"What are the chances of me solving this issue?" - Zero. You permanently deleted your data.

I am very careful what I do with Kali. I made my mistake using ubuntu. I only saw that it was readable on Kali and then went back into my primary OS. Unfortunately for me I got a bit brave while trying to find a way for my disk to be read. Next time I will be more patient. Thanks for the advice guys

What procedure did you use to change the file system from ntfs to ext4? I'd be very surprised that nothing warned you that you will lose all data when doing so. Also, the majority of linux distros have been able to read ntfs for a very long time. What version of Ubuntu are you running that is so old (more than 18 years or so) that it can't handle NTFS

I was being reckless. Nobody to blame but my impatience. I know that at one point my harddrive was ext4 and I changed it to ntfs. Filesystems is something that I do not know much about, I thought I'd put it back to the way it was and try again. I knew the risk, I was just impatient and suffered the consequences. In case anyone was curious..... PhotoRec has managed to bring back most of what was lost, plus things I didnt expect to find. Not everything but more thsn I expected. Its just  going to take me some time to go through everything and rename and reorder things. Impressive tool

The comments are answers:
Changing the filesystem means formatting the drive because the filesystem determines how data is written to that volume. Formatting means the data is essentially gone.
Normal data recovery processes can be followed, but there are already good questions and answers about data recovery, and you should find and follow those for that portion of your question.
As a general rule, Kali is a Linux flavor intended for a particular set of tasks and is not beginner-friendly. It can be used for primary computer use, but it is not INTENDED to be used as such, and so especially for beginners or even moderately experienced Linux users it is unwise to use it for that purpose. There are other flavors of Linux better suited for regular day-to-day use.

Yeah thanks.... I discovered that some time ago. Lesson learnt. Since then it is still on my system as a dual boot but I almost never use it. I use ubuntu as my day to day OS.
